# Access Class written in one python file From Another python file

Tags: python-3.x

I have 3 python file in same directory.
b.py

```
class Something_b():
    def b(self):
        print("hello from b")
```

c.py

```
class Something_c():
    def c(self):
        print("hello from c")
```

a.py

```
from .b import *
from .c import *

Something_b.b()
Something_c.c()
```

but i am getting some errors like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/testing/test1/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .b import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.b'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's fairly simple, just import the class from the file (you're importing all but you shouldn't put a period before the filename. The period before the filename is what's causing the error.)

## in file b:

```
class hello:
    def h(self):
        print("Hello")
```

## Then in file a:

```
from b import hello
hello.h('')
```

As you can see it printed hello, you can have as many files it doesn't really matter, when I'm doing a larger project I'll have a file for every key part of it. It makes it easier to read/find the function you are looking to edit.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:-**

a.py

```
from b import *
from c import *

x = Something_b()
x.b()
y = Something_c()
y.c()
```

Note:- First receipt class constructor then call belonging methods from class

Comment: It should work i tried it.Just copy and paste above programe.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/testing/test1/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .b import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.b'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: check  out in solution my import mdule is "from b import *"   it is not ".b"